# Struts XSS Prevention - Prevent a GET XSS

Tags: java, struts, xss

I have been able to prevent an XSS attack in struts 1.2 through a combination of filter="true" in the bean:write messages and by using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(string) in the tag libs I am using. However I can attack my site through an attack in the URL in the following form...

```
www.mysite.com/App/Start.do?logo=mylogo'><script>alert("ATTACK")</script>
```

Any advice on the best way to prevent this. I tried using a servlet filter but I don't want to convert all request inputs to special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I've found to block XSS is replacing all `>`, `<` and `"` characters with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;` before writing to the webpage. This should protect you from XSS so long as you aren't placing user input inside places such as script tags, image tags (XSS has been possible from the src= of image tags) etc as they won't be able to create their own tags.

In PHP you would do this with the [htmlSpecialChars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) method that encodes all characters like that. However Java doesn't have this method so the quickest way is to just replace those, you should really go through the entire list yourself. Shouldn't be too hard to implement 5 `replaceAll()`

---

The [docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) for the StringEscapeUtils method your using claims to perform what I suggest above, so you should check that your using the method correctly as your example shouldn't survive this form of prevention.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm talking specifically about the URL though, to prevent a user from hitting the above URL. OR intercepting all GET requests and cleanse those

Comment: Why does it matter if a URL contains XSS, the URL is not parsed as HTML. So it won't affect your site. This is purely an aesthetic issue?

Comment: I am able to insert javascript into the URL which will execute once the URL is hit.

Comment: After you recieve the GET request serverside, you should do what you like with it and either calling the escapeHtml4 method on it before you return it back in the HTML response or as soon as you extract it from the GET vars (the latter is not recommended unless you aren't processing the data). If you are replacing user input with the return from escapeHtml4 of the user input before putting it in the response, ***your example will not execute***. Hence back to my point of check your using the method correctly/in the right place.

Comment: @EricCallan If it's executing the JavaScript when the URL is hit then you're not filtering the request parameters: the parameters are set on the action form and processed by your action before coming near a browser.